# "Unsupported value: Tiramisu" while I try to set up the Android 13 SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-tiramisu, android-13

I followed this page: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/setup-sdk
to set up Android 13 SDK.

In my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion("Tiramisu")

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion("Tiramisu")
    }
}
```

Then I got the error:

```
> Unsupported value: Tiramisu. Format must be one of:
  - android-31
  - android-31-ext2
  - android-T
  - vendorName:addonName:31
```

I tried to use "33" instead of "Tiramisu", but it's not working.
I'm using the latest Android Studio Preview as the instruction.

Is there anyone trying to use Android 13 SDK?

Comment: "I'm using the latest Android Studio Preview" -- Dolphin? The [release notes mentions problems with Chipmunk](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/release-notes?hl=en#ki-studio-tools-dp1), though in a slightly different scenario.

Comment: I'm using Dolphin too, but when I change `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `"Tiramisu"`, I got the above error. And it's not about generating signed Apk, the error happens during the build.

Comment: Did you try using "android-T"?

Comment: @fillobotto Tried `T` instead of `Tiramisu`, it doesn't work too.

Comment: No, I mean the whole "android-T" string. When Q and S SDSs were still previews, we had to use "android-Q" or "android-S"

Comment: @fillobotto I got this `Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-T` - note that I already installed Android SDK Platform Tiramisu.

Comment: Try "android-Tiramisu"

Comment: @NickolaySavchenko `android-Tiramisu` is working great. Please post an answer and I will accept it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @nnhthuan feel free to accept your own answer:) For future Android releases you can open Android sdk folder and see names in `platforms` dir.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

| This answer is no longer valid because you can use API version 33 now for Tiramisu as it's officially released |
| --- |

Credit to @NickolaySavchenko - Posting this answer since I've been waiting for him for a day.

Finally, after taking advice from @NickolaySavchenko - I have a final working code like this.

```
compileSdkVersion "android-Tiramisu"
```

```
targetSdkVersion "Tiramisu"
```

Yes, you see it correctly, the `targetSdkVersion` is `Tiramisu`, not `android-Tiramisu` so that it can run in an emulator API Tiramisu device.

I tested and can confirm that `minSdkVersion` doesn't need to change to `android-Tiramisu` or `Tiramisu`. I'm still keeping it as `19` and it's working great.

Answer (score -2):

As @NickolaySavchenko said
compileSdkPreview "android-Tiramisu"
targetSdkPreview "android-Tiramisu"
working fine

and to run it on android 13 you also need to change your minSdk to "android-Tiramisu"

Comment: That's what we already discussed above. And it was the first answer by @NickolaySavchenko . Do not attempt to still the answer, it's not good at all. I'm waiting for him to officially answer here to accept it.

Comment: wow .. didn't see that coming .. by the way its not still its steal ..